# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on Swift.Result type .success but not .failure

Tags: swift

I'm implementing a function that retrieves an array of `ObjectA` then based on some filter will fetch an array of `ObjectB`.

While making the tests for this function I'm encountering a crash on calling my closure with a `.success` Result type.

The code is as follows:

```swift
struct ObjectA {}

struct ObjectB {}

protocol ObjectRetriever {
    func retrieveObjectAs(completion: @escaping (Result<[ObjectA], Error>) -> Void)
    func retrieveObjectBs(completion: @escaping (Result<[ObjectB], Error>) -> Void)
}

class MyRetriever: ObjectRetriever {
    func retrieveObjectAs(completion: @escaping (Result<[ObjectA], Error>) -> Void) {
        completion(.success([ObjectA()]))
    }
    
    func retrieveObjectBs(completion: @escaping (Result<[ObjectB], Error>) -> Void) {
        completion(.success([ObjectB()]))
    }
}

class SpyObjectRetriever: ObjectRetriever {
    enum ReceivedMessage: Equatable {
        case retrieveObjectAs
        case retrieveObjectBs
    }

    private(set) var receivedMessages = [ReceivedMessage]()

    private var retrieveObjectAsCompletions = [(Result<[ObjectA], Error>) -> Void]()
    private var retrieveObjectBsCompletions = [(Result<[ObjectB], Error>) -> Void]()
    
    func retrieveObjectAs(completion: @escaping (Result<[ObjectA], Error>) -> Void) {
        receivedMessages.append(.retrieveObjectAs)
        retrieveObjectAsCompletions.append(completion)
    }
    
    func retrieveObjectBs(completion: @escaping (Result<[ObjectB], Error>) -> Void) {
        receivedMessages.append(.retrieveObjectBs)
        retrieveObjectBsCompletions.append(completion)
    }
    
    func completeRetrieveObjectAs(with error: Error, at index: Int = 0) {
        retrieveObjectAsCompletions[index](.failure(error))
    }
    
    func completeRetrieveObjectAs(with objects: [ObjectA], at index: Int = 0) {
        retrieveObjectAsCompletions[index](.success(objects))
    }
    
    func completeRetrieveObjectBs(with error: Error, at index: Int = 0) {
        retrieveObjectBsCompletions[index](.failure(error))
    }
    
    func completeRetrieveObjectBs(with objects: [ObjectB], at index: Int = 0) {
        retrieveObjectBsCompletions[index](.success(objects))
        //                         ^ crash occurs here with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        
        // When putting a breakpoint here and calling `retrieveObjectBsCompletions.first?(.failure(NSError(domain: "Test", code: 0)))`
        // No problem, the test fails, because I expect an empty array, but no crash
        
        // However, when calling `retrieveObjectBsCompletions.first?(.success([]))`
        // App crashes with the following error
        // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x400000000000008).
        // The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
        
        // When inspecting `retrieveObjectBsCompletions.first` I get either
        // ▿ Optional<(Result<Array<ObjectB>, Error>) -> ()>
        //   - some : (Function)
        // or
        // 0x0000000100bd428c $__lldb_expr190`reabstraction thunk helper from @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed Swift.Result<Swift.Array<ObjectB>, Swift.Error>) -> (@out ()) to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed Swift.Result<Swift.Array<ObjectB>, Swift.Error>) -> () + 160
    }
}

class MyClass {
    let retriever: ObjectRetriever
    
    init(retriever: ObjectRetriever) {
        self.retriever = retriever
    }
    
    func retrieveObjectBsBasedOnValueOfObjectAs(completion: @escaping (Result<[ObjectB], Error>) -> Void) {
        retriever.retrieveObjectAs { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case let .failure(error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            case let .success(objectAs):
                guard !objectAs.isEmpty else {
                    completion(.success([]))
                    return
                }
                self.checkObjectAsAndFetchObjectBs(objectAs, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func checkObjectAsAndFetchObjectBs(_ objectAs: [ObjectA], completion: @escaping (Result<[ObjectB], Error>) -> Void) {
        // do something with objectAs to filter them
        retriever.retrieveObjectBs { [weak self] result in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            switch result {
            case let .failure(error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            case let .success(objectBs):
                completion(.success(objectBs))
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyTest {
    func run() {
        let retriever = SpyObjectRetriever()
        let sut = MyClass(retriever: retriever)
        
        sut.retrieveObjectBsBasedOnValueOfObjectAs { [weak self] result in
            guard self != nil else { return }
            switch result {
            case let .failure(error):
                print("Got error: \(error)")
            case let .success(objectBs):
                print("Got objetcBs: \(objectBs)")
            }
        }
        
        retriever.completeRetrieveObjectAs(with: [ObjectA()])
        retriever.completeRetrieveObjectBs(with: [ObjectB()])
    }
}

MyTest().run()
```

I've run this code in a Playground and cannot reproduce the error, but all the relevant code is there.

I've never experienced a crash like this before. Any idea why the `.failure` case does not crash but the `.success` does?

FYI, I'm using the exact same spy in a different test class and there no issues.
The crash is not systematic, but happens 99% of the time.
I just don't understand how this can crash...

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue with the provided code while not in a playground?

Comment: I extracted the code into a Playground to check if I could reproduce it there, but no. I just found the origin of the crash and posted an answer to my own question. The issue was not where I expected it to be and was not in the code shown above. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, I found the origin of the crash and wow...

After retrieving my array of `ObjectA`, I was mapping them to get only a reference identifier to ObjectBs.
In order to not have duplicate but keep the order in which `ObjectA`s were retrieved I used `NSOrderedSet`.
Then I would loop on those ids.

### Before

```swift
let uniqueObjectBIds: [String] = Array(_immutableCocoaArray: NSOrderedSet(array: retrievedObjectBIds))
```

Which is not producing what I expected, if I inspect `uniqueObjectBIds` I get:

```
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:575: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

### After

The solution was to simply use `NSOrderedSet` like this:

```swift
let uniqueObjectBIds = NSOrderedSet(array: retrievedObjectBIds)
```

Which produces a `Set` of `Any` that I can then cast as `String` in my loop

```swift
for id in uniqueObjectBIds {
  if let stringId = id as? String {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: You may want to use uniqueObjectBIds.compactMap { $0 as? String }.forEach {} unless you do something else with the id(s) that are not a String

Comment: This was for demo purpose, I do not use it like that, but thanks for the comment